# How to find witch(nth) option is selected by jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to find the selected nth child of a select option to synchronized select the same nth child in another form.
below is the code I have tried but no success.
http://jsfiddle.net/63ngb428/1/

```
<select id="name1" name="name1">
    <option value="11">111</option>
    <option value="22">222</option>
    <option value="33">333</option>
    <option value="44">444</option>
</select>
<select id="name2" name="name1">
    <option value="55">555</option>
    <option value="66">666</option>
    <option value="77">777</option>
    <option value="88">888</option>
</select>
<select id="name3" name="name1">
    <option value="99">999</option>
    <option value="00">000</option>
    <option value="xx">xxx</option>
    <option value="yy">yyy</option>
</select>

$('#name1').change(function () {
    var selected = $("#name1 option").eq();
    $('select[name="name1"] option:nth-child(selected)').attr('selected', 'selected');
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('#name1').change(function () {
    var selected = $("option:selected",this).index();
    $('select[name="name1"] option').filter(function() {
        return $(this).index() == selected;
  }).attr('selected', 'selected');
});
```

You have to use `.index()`

**Demo**

```js
$('#name1').change(function () {
 var selected = $("option:selected",this).index();
 $('select[name="name1"] option').filter(function() {
  return $(this).index() == selected;
  }).attr('selected', 'selected');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="name1" name="name1">
    <option value="11">111</option>
    <option value="22">222</option>
    <option value="33">333</option>
    <option value="44">444</option>
</select>
<select id="name2" name="name1">
    <option value="55">555</option>
    <option value="66">666</option>
    <option value="77">777</option>
    <option value="88">888</option>
</select>
<select id="name3" name="name1">
    <option value="99">999</option>
    <option value="00">000</option>
    <option value="xx">xxx</option>
    <option value="yy">yyy</option>
</select>
```

Comment: thank you. it worked for me and with my current jquery version.

Comment: No problem, happy to help

Answer (score 1):

To find the index of the selected `option` use `index()`, not `eq()`. Then you can use `find()` along with `:nth-child()` to select the `option` elements in the other selects which have the same index.

Also note the version of jQuery being used in your fiddle, 1.4.4, is *very* outdated. You should really update it ASAP.

```js
$('#name1').change(function() {
  var selected = $("#name1 option:selected").index();
  console.log(selected);
  
  $('select[name="name1"]').find(`option:nth-child(${selected + 1})`).prop('selected', true);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="name1" name="name1">
  <option value="11">111</option>
  <option value="22">222</option>
  <option value="33">333</option>
  <option value="44">444</option>
</select>
<select id="name2" name="name1">
  <option value="55">555</option>
  <option value="66">666</option>
  <option value="77">777</option>
  <option value="88">888</option>
</select>
<select id="name3" name="name1">
  <option value="99">999</option>
  <option value="00">000</option>
  <option value="xx">xxx</option>
  <option value="yy">yyy</option>
</select>
```

Comment: thank you. it's true and your code is working with higher version of jquery.